# Can some help debug this javascript, I can't see what I'm doing wrong

Tags: javascript, html, menu, onclick

Well I've got a menu that declares variables with onclick, now 1 to 4 works as expected but function pagefivevar isn't showing the result on alert:

Html menu:

```
<a id="page1" href="" onclick="pageonevar('page1')">Home</a>
    <a id="page2" href="" onclick="pagetwovar('page2')">About us</a>
    <a id="page3" href="" onclick="pagethreevar('page3')">Services</a>
    <a id="page4" href="" onclick="pagefourvar('page4')">Partners</a>
    <a id="page5" href="" onlcick="pagefivevar('page5')">Contact us</a>
```

Javascript functions:

```
<script>
    var var1="";
    function pageonevar(varcontent){
      var1=varcontent;
      alert(var1);
    }
    function pagetwovar(varcontent){
      var1=varcontent;
      alert(var1);
    }
    function pagethreevar(varcontent){
      var1=varcontent;
      alert(var1);
    }
    function pagefourvar(varcontent){
      var1=varcontent;
      alert(var1);
    }
    function pagefivevar(varcontent){
      var1=varcontent;
      alert(var1);
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: you have a typo : onlcick instead of onclick on last row

Answer (score 2):

In the line

```
<a id="page5" href="" onlcick="pagefivevar('page5')">Contact us</a>
```

should be

```
<a id="page5" href="" onclick="pagefivevar('page5')">Contact us</a>
```

I changed `onlcick` to `onclick`

Comment: Wow sorry for wasting your time, feel such an idiot now lol.

Comment: @TimMarshall No worries!  You have to learn one way or another.  If it helped, feel free to select this as the answer.  Then it really isn't wasted time!

Answer (score 2):

`onlcick` is a typo, use `onclick` instead.

Answer (score 1):

modify Html menu 5th line:

```
<a id="page5" href="" onclick="pagefivevar('page5')">Contact us</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just a typo that's caused this (onlcick instead of onclick on your 5th a), but perhaps you could avoid all this repetition with:

```
<a id="page1" href="" onclick="loadPage('page1')">Home</a>
<a id="page2" href="" onclick="loadPage('page2')">About us</a>
<a id="page3" href="" onclick="loadPage('page3')">Services</a>
<a id="page4" href="" onclick="loadPage('page4')">Partners</a>
<a id="page5" href="" onclick="loadPage('page5')">Contact Us</a>

<script>
function loadPage(varcontent){
  alert(varcontent)
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip, though i tried this approach before but in a different way didn't work so that's why there was so much repetition.